# Deleting specific lines in a text file based one 1 variable

Tags: c++, arrays, storage

Currently got 4 different variables, saved in the format of:

artist:title:year:category

I am currently opening the file and saving into corresponding variables, I have tried using getline, but unable to get it to delete all the corresponding variables.

```
void deletesong(){

    string oldfile;
    ifstream openFile;
    ofstream ofile;
    string line;
    string songnme;
    string oartist[NUM], otitle[NUM], oyear[NUM], ocategory[NUM];
    int counter;
    bool finddvd;
    //User enters filename, add .txt to make sure its saved as filename.txt
    do{
    cout  << "Please enter the name of the file you would like to delete from: ";
    cin >> oldfile;
    oldfile +=  ".txt";
    openFile.open(oldfile.c_str());
        if(openFile.fail()){
            cerr << "Check spelling of file name.\n";
            error = true;
        }
    //Storing text from file into arrays
    }while(error == true);

    while(getline( openFile, oartist[counter], ':') && getline( openFile, otitle[counter], ':') &&
        getline( openFile, oyear[counter], ':') && getline( openFile, ocategory[counter])){
    counter++;
    }
    cout << "Enter the name of the song you would like to delete: ";
    cin >> songname;
```

This is the code I am using to retrive the filename, and then open the file and save everything into the arrays.

What I need my code to do is to for example is if someone wants to delete a song name of Ruby, it will be in the textfile as

xxxx:Ruby:xxxx:xxxx

I need the program to delete all the information on the line as its one record.

Comment: Take out a blank piece of paper and a pen. Write down, in plain English, a logical step by step process for doing what you want to do. After you have done so, just translate the written process directly into C++. If you cannot write down the logical process for implementing this, your question has nothing to do with C++. If you can, but you have a problem translating some part of it into code, show what you have implemented so far, with a ***specific*** question. Otherwise, stackoverflow.com is not a code-writing service.

Comment: I am not asking for anyone to write it, I'm just asking for suggestions on how to complete it, I have tried using getline to create a newfile and copy the contents of the old file and exclude the line deleted, but could not get all of the information to be deleted with it. I will rewrite this code now and edit the post, but I was thinking there might be something simpler.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to use `std::vector<std::string>` rather than declaring array of strings, such as `string oartist[NUM]`.

In addition, you can organize your data in to one structure. For example:

```
struct record
{
    std::string artist, title, year, category;
};
```

Use `std::vector::push_back` to add data. You can then remove records which are in the middle of the vector, or you can add new data to the vector. Finally save the data. For example:

```
std::fstream openFile(filename, std::ios::in);
if (openFile.fail()) return;

record rec;
std::vector<record> songs;

while ( getline(openFile, rec.artist, ':') && 
    getline(openFile, rec.title, ':') && 
    getline(openFile, rec.year, ':') && 
    getline(openFile, rec.category) )
    songs.push_back(rec);

std::string title_remove = "title";

for (size_t i = 0; i < songs.size(); i++)
{
    if (songs[i].title == title_remove)
    {
        songs.erase(songs.begin() + i);
        break;
    }
}

openFile.close();

openFile.open(filename, std::ios::out);
for (size_t i = 0; i < songs.size(); i++)
    openFile << songs[i].artist << ":" 
    << songs[i].title << ":" 
    << songs[i].year << ":" 
    << songs[i].category << "\n";
```

Note that this example uses `fstream` instead of using `ofstream`. That's because it needs to open the file for reading, then close the file, and open it again with `ios::out` flag for writing.

---

Edit, to do this with fixed sized arrays:

```
void deletedvd() 
{
    string oldfile;
    ifstream openFile;
    string line, dvdnme;
    ofstream createFile;
    string oartist[NUM], otitle[NUM], oyear[NUM], ocategory[NUM];
    string nartist[NUM], ntitle[NUM], nyear[NUM], ncategory[NUM];

    //**********
    //initialize these values before using them
    //**********
    int counter = 0;
    int j = 0;
    bool error = false;
    bool searc = false;

    //User enters filename, add .txt to make sure its saved as filename.txt
    do {
        cout << "Please enter the name of the file you would like to delete from: ";
        cin >> oldfile;
        oldfile += ".txt";
        openFile.open(oldfile);
        if (openFile.fail()) {
            cerr << "Check spelling of file name.\n";
            error = true;
        }
    } while (error == true);
    cout << "Enter the name of the dvd you would like to delete: ";
    cin >> dvdnme;
    while (getline(openFile, oartist[counter], ':') && getline(openFile, otitle[counter], ':') &&
        getline(openFile, oyear[counter], ':') && getline(openFile, ocategory[counter])) {
        counter++;
    }

    //Loop for finding the deleted word, and overwriting it by shifting every to right of it left by 1 element
    for (int i = 0; i < counter; i++)
    {
        if (dvdnme == otitle[i])
        {
            //**** skip this item
            searc = true;
            continue;
        }
        ntitle[j] = otitle[i];
        nartist[j] = oartist[i];
        nyear[j] = oyear[i];
        ncategory[j] = ocategory[i];
        j++;
    }

    if (searc)
    {
        //**********
        //close this file handle before opening a new handle
        //**********
        openFile.close();

        createFile.open(oldfile);//**** doesn't need the .c_str() with other std function
        for (int i = 0; i < counter - 1; i++) {
            createFile << ntitle[i] << ":" << nartist[i] << ":" << nyear[i]
                << ":" << ncategory[i] << endl;
        }
        createFile.close();
    }
}
```

Comment: Why do you need to use fixed arrays?